# Strict ng-model value in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, boolean, angular-ngmodel, typechecking

How to assign strict value to ng-model, so that `""` not equal to  `false`. and radio got deseleted when `names` equals `""`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ''
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<input type="radio" ng-model="names" ng-value="false" >select only when model is false not ""

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Assigning this value in your controller isn't working as you wish ?

Comment: @Zooly yes i want radio got deselect when value is "", i updated the question accordingly

Comment: You may have to write a function that gives/removes attribute `checked` to the radio button input depends of the value of the model.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exact behavior you are looking for but, you could put a function in ng-checked that takes names as an argument to implement the behavior you want.

input tag

```
ng-checked="myValue(names)"
```

controller

```
$scope.myValue = function(names) {
  if (names === '') {
    ...
  }
}
```